# How to check/test if string is static or dynamic and could be editable

Tags: c

Here we have 3 strings:

```
char  a1[ ] = "abc"; // static
char  a2[4] = "abc"; // static 
char* a3    = "abc"; // dynamic
```

test function is only as example

```
int test(char* v)
{
  return (*v = '1')
}
```

Lets test in main and results

```
int main()
{

  int n;

  n = test(a1); // OK// 
  // if not '1' use malloc else leave it
  n = test(a2); // OK
  // if not '1' use malloc else leave it
  n = test(a3); // const Error
  // if not '1' use malloc else leave it
}
```

How a3 pointer could be tested/ checked? so you could take actions like malloc(); coz it non editable so we need new pointer.

Comment: I've found a way to test this. But it's a Unix-only solution. Are you interested?

Comment: Suggest `const char* a3 = "abc";`.  Then `test(a3)` fails at compile time.  It is only an artifact of C history that even allows `char* a3 = "abc";`

Answer (score 1):

`test(a3);` causes a segmentation fault, as you're trying to write a read-only memory area of your process. So yes, you've tested whether it's writable, but the test fails by crashing.

What's the point in testing write-access?

- success destroys the original string
- failure crashes your program

They are all your own variables, you should know what they are. Or am I missing something?

And what do you mean by static/dynamic? Do you mean read-only / writable?

C is a minimalistic portable assembler. It has no introspection. It does not store all sorts of information about its data. So it cannot be done.

Comment: Dynamic array could use malloc.do you know how to test/check 'a3'?

Comment: Your comment states `char *a3 = "abc";` is dynamic. What's dynamic about that? It's the most static/constant of them all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the crash isn't that `a3` is a pointer.  It's that the memory it points to is a constant compiled into the program, and therefore can't be changed.

There is no standardized way of testing whether or not this is the case.  It's against the C philosophy to provide a feature that would require run-time overhead that many programmers won't use.

So, you're responsible for keeping track of this, if that's something you need.

One thing you might look at is using a security-checker like [splint](http://splint.org/), which I understand scans your code for such potential problems.

Comment: I need asnwer "YES it's possible" write code this under C tag not under talk tag.

Comment: @flexe tough cookies. "yes it's possible" is not a correct answer.  It can't be done.

Comment: @Kevin if you don't know how it doesn't mean "it can't be done". if C exists this is possible.

Comment: @flexe If you have specific knowledge of the memory layout for that specific combination of compiler and system you might be able to guess based on the memory range. Short of that, if you have a pointer and you don't know exactly where it came from, you can't know whether it's safe to write to. Like John says, C just doesn't carry runtime metadata.

Comment: @flexe This seems like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/172958). What is your actual end goal? There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: My question is about test/check if it's static or dynamic and take action if it's non editable. give me unsafe example coz your 20K reputation should be worth something? or nothing? answer = no(is weak) I think my 2 points are equal your 20K points just saying

Comment: @Kevin my goal is if it's dynamic function will pass it to malloc();

Comment: @flexe if you KNOW it's possible, please tell us how. Because we don't know. Our reputation may be worth nothing, but we want to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a Unix-only solution. The `readonly()` function forks, and does @flexe's proposed test in the child process. Two advantages:

- the parent process' original data is not overwritten
- the parent process can check if the child segfaulted when attemting to write read-only memory.

The function below returns true if pointer `p` points to readonly memory.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int readonly(void *p)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (pid == 0) { /* CHILD */
        *(char *)p = 0; /* Causes segfault if buffer not writable */
        exit(0);        /* Otherwise child exits normally */
    } else { /* PARENT */
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        return WIFSIGNALED(status);
    }
}
```